# Commuting quaternions

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, lie-groups, quaternions

I tried to solve the following exercise, please could somebody tell me if I did it right?:

> Prove that non-real elements $x,y \in \mathbb H$ commute if and only
>   if their imaginary parts are parallel, that is, $\Im(x) = \lambda \Im
>  y$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb R$.

For this I would like to use the following (without proof): Two vectors  $x,y \in \mathbb R^3$ are parallel if and only if $x \times y = 0$. Also, it is easy to see that $\Im (xy) = x \times y$ and $x \cdot y = -\Re(xy)$.

Now first let $x,y \in \mathbb H$ be two purely imaginary quaternions. Therefore they equal their imaginary parts: $x = \Im x, y = \Im y$.

Assume the imaginary parts of $x$ and $y$ are parallel. Then

$$  xy = \Im (xy) + \Re(xy) = \Re(xy) = - x \cdot y = - y \cdot x = \Re(yx) = yx$$

Next assume that $xy = yx$. Then 
$$x \times y = \Im (xy) = \Im (yx) = y \times x = - x \times y$$

hence $x \times y = 0$ and therefore $x,y$ are parallel.

Since the claim holds for purely imaginary quaternions and since the real component of a quaterion commutes with all the other parts the claim follows.

Comment: Purely imaginary quaternion $\;\neq\;$ non-real quaternion. And why would two purely imaginary quaternions have equal imaginary parts?

Comment: They don't necessarily have, but they *equal to* their imaginary part, as being purely imaginary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, everything is correct.

Maybe you should also spell out for the last part that $a+u$ commutes with $b+v$ (with $a,b\in\Bbb R$ and $u,v$ purely imaginary), iff $u$ and $v$ commutes.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I should spell it out, you are right.

Comment: I would upvote, too, but I don't have enough reputation since they have not merged me with [my unregistered previous account](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/156078/learner).